# Getting attachments from gmail using AE.NET not working

Tags: c#, gmail-imap

I am using [AE.NET](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) to get mail from Gmail using IMAP. I am able to get the messages, however when I try iterate over the message attachments there are none. Returning message.Value.Attachments.Count() gives me 0.

```
using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", mailAccount.UserName, mailAccount.Password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
{
    //Get all new messages
    var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(
        SearchCondition.Unseen()
    );
    string ret = "";

    foreach (var message in msgs)
    {
        foreach (var attachment in message.Value.Attachments)
        {
            //Save the attachment
        }
    }
}
```

As I said I have logged the attachment count along with the subject of the mail and am sure that the mails are being retrieved however they have no attachments, which is not true because I can see the attachments in Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen())` only, but this method loads only the headers of the mail. You need to use the code below by message's ids that you got in the `SearchMessages` method:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage> mails = new List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage>();

using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", mailAccount.UserName, mailAccount.Password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true)) 
{
    var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen());
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++) {
        string msgId = msgs[i].Uid;
        ids.Add(msgId);            
    }

    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        mails.Add(imap.GetMessage(id, headersonly: false));
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
foreach(var msg in mails)
{
    foreach (var att in msg.Attachments) 
    {
        string fName;
        fName = att.Filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", mailAccount.UserName, mailAccount.Password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))  {
        var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen());
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++) {
            MailMessage msg = msgs[i].Value;

            foreach (var att in msg.Attachments) {
                string fName;
                fName = att.Filename;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

icon. As the author does not provide any pre-built downloads, you must compile it yourself. (I believe you can get it through NuGet though). There is no longer a .dll in the bin/ folder.  There is no documentation, which I consider a downside, but I was able to whip this up by looking at the source code (yay for open source!) and using Intellisense. The below code connects specifically to Gmail's IMAP server:

```
// Connect to the IMAP server. The 'true' parameter specifies to use SSL 
// which is important (for Gmail at least) 
ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "name@gmail.com", "pass", ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true); 
// Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX"); Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount()); 
// Get the first *11* messages. 0 is the first message; 
// and it also includes the 10th message, which is really the eleventh ;) 
// MailMessage represents, well, a message in your mailbox 
MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10); 
foreach (MailMessage m in mm) {     
   Console.WriteLine(m.Subject); 
} // Probably wiser to use a using statement ic.Dispose();
```